Set up Azure app service calling public access disabled function app that has private endpoint
Via terraform azurerm, my objective is to have an Azure vnet with an app service in one subnet called "default" and a functions app in another subnet called "functions".
The function app will have "public network access" set to disabled.
The Azure App Service should be able to call the functions app using a private endpoint set up for the functions app.
But when I place the functions app in the "functions" subnet without a delegation, I get an error

Function is missing a delegation to "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"

But then I give the functions subnet a delegation to Microsoft.Web/serverFarms and then the private endpoint creation fails with

Private Endpoint Name: "my-function-app-name-develop-storage-account-private-endpoint"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: PrivateEndpointCreationNotAllowedAsSubnetIsDelegated: Private endpoint /subscriptions//resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/my-function-app-name-develop-storage-account-private-endpoint cannot be created as subnet /subscriptions//resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-resource-group-vnet/subnets/default is delegated


Ended up going with

Private endpoint using the "functions" subnet and that subnet is not "delegated"
VNET integration to default subnet which is delegated to "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"

This worked... not sure what this means in practical networking terms so if anyone has anything eloquent to say in that regard I'm all ears! :)
